# Transate plugin with js & wp_localize_script

Tags: php, plugin-development, translation, wp-localize-script

I'm trying to translate a plugin with JS functionality.
I was able to translate the classic php part with a .po file etc...

In my plugin there are 2 words in js that I would like to translate and I absolutely can't get it to work

When I regenerate my .po file and I indicate that there is a translation for the js file, the software tells me the word that I can translate but the translate not work

**JS example**

```
const message = {
    'copy': 'it's okay !',
};

buttonclip.on('success', function(e){
    e.trigger.textContent = message.copy;
});
```

**PHP functions**

```
function js_script(){
  wp_localize_script('code-js', 'messageClip', array('copy' => __('its okay', 'textdomain'),));

  wp_enqueue_script  ('code-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/main.js', array('framework_js'), 1.0, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_script');
```

Comment: Have a look at [the wordpress codex on internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/internationalization/#internationalizing-javascript), it should explain everything how to internationalize your js scripts the "wordpress way" ;) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP you are localizing the script using `wp_localize_script()`. The way you've used it will create an object in JS named `messageClip` with the string as the `copy` property, but then in your JavaScript you're not actually using this. In your JavaScript just get rid of `const message` etc. and use:

```
buttonclip.on('success', function(e){
    e.trigger.textContent = messageClip.copy;
});
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much :)